# Login PHP it's not working

Tags: php, mysql, session, post

Is this code ok? I try to make a php login page but it's not working...Can you help me? Below is the source of php page. The form is written in ExtJs.

```
<?php
$loginUsername = isset($_POST["loginUsername"]) ? $_POST["loginUsername"] : "";
$loginPassword = isset($_POST["loginPassword"]) ? $_POST["loginPassword"] : "";

/*if($loginUsername == "f"){
    echo "{success: true}";
} else {
    echo "{success: false, errors: { reason: 'Login failed. Try again.' }}";
}*/
//Baza de datesession_start();
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
mysql_select_db("hgr",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE username='" . $loginUsername . "' and parola = '". $loginUsername."'");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
echo "{success: true}";
$_SESSION["userid"] = $row[id];
$_SESSION["username"] = $row[username];
$_SESSION["nume"] = $row[nume];
$_SESSION["casa"] = $row[casa];
$_SESSION["rol"] = $row[nivel_acces];
} else {
echo "{success: false, errors: { reason: 'Login failed. Try again.' }}";
}

?>
```

Comment: The DB field `parola` is this also the `username` or should this be the password?

Comment: [**`session_start()`**](http://us1.php.net//manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: `and parola = '". $loginPassword ."'`

Comment: have a look at SQL-Injection. Also, please post what is not working, what is your HTML, what is the error message, if any, you get, what have you tried and so on. "it's not working" is no valid error description.

Comment: I changed @Sven but still is not working

Comment: @Joshua if i dont work with DB and verify like this 'if($loginUsername == "f"){
    echo "{success: true}";
} else {
    echo "{success: false, errors: { reason: 'Login failed. Try again.' }}";
}' it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many errors in your code :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE username='" . $loginUsername . "' and parola = '". $loginUsername."'");
```

You check username and parola on same var.
You probably want :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM utilizatori WHERE username='" . $loginUsername . "' and parola = '". $loginPassword."'");
```

You are also affecting vars without quotes :

```
$_SESSION["userid"] = $row['id'];
```

Check also this :

- [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to send your message in JSON instead of writing it yourself
- [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or PDO cause you're using mysql_* which is deprecated
- mysql injections in your query

Comment: Good simplified copy paste of my answer.

Comment: I tried but is not working..

Comment: @Darren : I was writing at the same time

Comment: Find that hard to believe but I won't down-vote it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't have [**`session_start()`**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.session-start.php) set anywhere, so you're sessions aren't being handled/instantiated.
Easily fixed by including this to the top of your script:

```
session_start();
```

Now you should **STOP** writing our your json and instead use `json_encode()` to create proper json.
That is done by doing something like the following:

```
json_encode(array('success'=> false, 'errors' => array('reason' => 'Login failed. Try again.')));
```

Which will return your desired json string:

```
{"success": false, "errors": { "reason": "Login failed. Try again." }}
```

And the last issue is in your query; you have this:

```
and parola = '". $loginUsername."'"
```

which should be:

```
and parola = '". $loginPassword."'"
```

---

## NOTES

You should avoid **mysql_*** functions as they are depreciated. You should however look into [**`PDO prepared statements`**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [**`MySQLi`**](https://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I made the changes but it's still not working...

Comment: Are there any errors showing?

Comment: the only error is "The username or password is incorect"

Comment: @Fred-ii- if you get the notification I can see why you've done what you've done.

Comment: @Alex what was the issue?